# How can I set keep UI elements the same size they were prior to adding a launch image on the iPhone 6/6+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, autolayout

At the end of developing my first app, I finally added the launch image. The interface of my entire app completely changed.

I used autolayout, but I didn't realize that setting the heights and widths for particular elements would bite me in the ass later. I am using a heavily art-based app so the objects really need to be specific sizes on certain VCs. I have a question:

How do I replace all of my explicit sizes with relative ones? I want them to look identical in size to the iphone 5s and smaller displays. Right now I place the elements using autolayout, but set their sizes explicitly in storyboard. (using width/height constraint) I want to keep the sizes on the 5s and lower.

I've played around with Adaptive UI to set the sizes individually but I don't think there is a size class exclusive to the 6/6+ so that won't work. The individual height/width constraints that I set are carried over to smaller size displays so I end up ruining the 4 inch and lower display size interface.

How is this possible?

Comment: What's the significance of the "adding a launch image" step?  If you remove the launch image does it go back to your desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, because it reverts back to the 4.5 inch display scaling.

Comment: Is text size an issue? Matts enser assume it is but u can't see that in your question.

Comment: The issue is the sizing of ui elements such as imageviews and buttons. The best success I have had is using aspect ratio as described here [link](http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/easier-percentage-width-in-autolayout.html) , which does the best job aside from the amount of work it is to properly set the multiple for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Relative size is easy; just set up constraints that give you values relative to the size of the superview (which is sized to the screen), instead of absolute heights and widths.

That solves the problem for *images*. For text, however - e.g. UILabels - text at a certain size (say 14 pt) on a small device gets lost on a big device. So the solution would be to make your text sizes literally larger on the larger device. Auto layout can't help with that; you will have to use code to detect what device type this is (or what the screen size is) and adjust the fonts of all your interface objects to compensate.

Comment: It's weird that there's no 'easy' way to automatically increase/decrease font according to screen size.

Comment: Okay, there sort of is one way. Use Dynamic Type fonts. This allows the _user_ to set the size. - But sure, I agree with you. Apple threw the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus at developers without thinking this through.

Comment: for my imageView, when I have the leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints connect to the superview the image is offscreen.

Comment: I've tried adjusting constants in a million ways possible, nothing appears to solve the issue.

Comment: @CaptainCOOLGUY Both "in a million ways" and "solve the issue" are totally vague. I've answered to the question to extent that you asked it and to the extent that you gave any information. If you have _specific_ issues, ask a new question and this time be _specific_ about what you are doing, what is resulting, and what result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexBrown That seems like flapdoodle to me, since all iPhones have the same size classes. If you can be more specific and prove me wrong, please submit your solution as an answer, as you would be greatly assisting the developer community.

Answer (score 1):

For images, setting aspect ratio is very useful.

PS: If you want the app to look the same on bigger phones as on smaller ones, but "zoomed" you can delete the launch images for bigger phones, that would force the app to use iPhone 5's layout.

Comment: Yes, someone gave this answer and then deleted it. I don't understand why it was deleted; it's a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: @matt The problem with this answer is that Apple at some point will make it mandatory to natively support all screen sizes.

Comment: @DaniA I bet you're right. It isn't an approach I'd actually advise. But it isn't false! :)